# How do I evaluate this limit using an integral?

Tags: calculus

I need a help to evaluate the following limit.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n \sin\left(k\cdot \pi\over 2n\right)   }$$
I tried transforming into a sum using $a=\exp(\ln a)$ but I did something wrong at calculating an integral.

Comment: Maybe by taking the log of the whole expression you will get :
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log(\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2n}))
$$

Answer (score 2):

You may also prove by exploiting $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $n$-th roots of unity that
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n} = \frac{2n}{2^n} \tag{1}$$
from which
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n} = \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)^2 = \frac{4n}{4^n} \tag{2} $$
and
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n} = \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{2^n} \tag{3}$$
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n}}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{4} $$
This shows how the well-known integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(x)\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$ and the well-known identity $(1)$ are indeed equivalent.

Comment: This was really nice. +1 Handling it via roots of unity appears so much natural compared to the Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n \sin\left(k\cdot \pi\over 2n\right)   }= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log(\sin\left(k\cdot \pi\over 2n\right)) \to \int_0^1 \log( \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x).$$

Your turn !

Comment: I think your product sign in the second expression should be a sum sign.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271281/integration-of-log-sin-x

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{k\pi}{2n}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\sin\frac{k\pi}{2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin x\,dx=\int_0^1\log\sin\left(\frac\pi2x\right)\,dx$$